# MAAS Moving KVM Machines between pods

Tags: maas, kvm-virtualization

Is there a way to move **KVM** machines running on a [pod](https://maas.io/tutorials/create-kvm-pods-with-maas#1-overview) to another pod?

I want to be able to move (migrate) machines (guests) running on servers (hosts). I'm looking for similar/same functionality as KVM Migrations.

Servers are all:

1. in the same subnet 10.10.1.0/24
2. same arch [Linux dear-insect 4.15.0-74-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 08:06:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux]
3. running as maas kvm pods

In an environment setup without using maas I am able to perform migrations from the cli and from virt-manager. So I am looking for the same functionality in environments under maas control.

Comment: Which kind of pod? MAAS supports two types of pods, (1) Physical systems with Intel RSD and (2) Virtual Machines with KVM (using the virsh interface). 3) Have you verified, if you are moving to a pod with different resources, that the VM will run OK on the destination pod? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.